# Multisite - mix sites that use subdomains with sites that use paths

Tags: multisite

We've got a WordPress Multisite install.

Can you mix sites that use subdomains with sites that use paths?

And, if so, are there any guides to this?

Answer (score 0):

The [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network#Step_3:_Installing_a_Network) says you have to choose one option or the other. What might work is to choose the sub-directory option and then on your server (via cPanel or whatever control panel you have) setup some subdomains to point at those folders/urls.

I have not done any tests on this but that would be my approach.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You might see the solution on using [Multi Network](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-multi-network/) a plugin that will allow you to create multiple networks within your Multisite.

After you install you use the Path based Installation and if you ever need a subdomain you just create a new network with that domain.